# Why can't I use pip packages from the command line?

Tags: python, windows, cmd, pip

I get the following output and it's making me crazy. I'm on Windows with pip 20.2.2 and Python 3.9.0rc1, however this has been the same for Python 3.8.5

```
C:\Users\chad>pip install ffmpeg
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: ffmpeg in c:\users\chad\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (1.4)

C:\Users\chad>ffmpeg
'ffmpeg' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

My user variables for Path are the following:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;%PyCharm Community Edition%;C:\Program Files\Python38;C:\Users\chad\AppData\Roaming\Python;C:\Users\chad\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages;C:\Users\chad\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\;C:\Users\chad\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts;c:\users\chad\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages;
```

My system variables for Path are the following:

```
C:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Python39\;%INTEL_DEV_REDIST%redist\intel64\compiler;C:\Program Files\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Python38\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\chad\AppData\Roaming\Python;C:\Users\chad\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\;C:\Users\chad\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts;c:\users\chad\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages;
```

Comment: Is `ffmpeg` actually on your `PATH`?

Comment: Also note that the [`ffmpeg`](https://pypi.org/project/ffmpeg/) Python package doesn't install the `ffmpeg` binary.

Comment: I would advise you to fix your path variables too, IMO, you have duplicated entries and their order is important too. My suggestion would be, **User:** `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;%PyCharm Community Edition%;C:\Users\chad\AppData\Roaming\Python;C:\Users\chad\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages;C:\Users\chad\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages;C:\Users\chad\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts;C:\Users\chad\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages;` I kept `%PyCharm Community Edition%` in there for now, despite its content being unknown!

Comment: And for **System:** `C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;%INTEL_DEV_REDIST%redist\intel64\compiler;C:\Program Files\Python39;C:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Python38;C:\Program Files\Python38\Scripts;`

Comment: @AaronKeesing weird... That's what worked before

Answer (score 0):

Don’t confuse Python module (which needs a python interpreter to be run) and a single binary which contains compiled source code or machine code (then that could run « freely »  ).

Pip is the package manager for python, installing then modules for python.

PS: for ffmpeg, depending on your operating system, you can use a package manager to install and keep it updated. On macOS, brew install ffmepg, will do the job

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg is a **python module** and you can import it on run it only with a **python interpreter**

```
Python 2.7.18rc1 (default, Apr  7 2020, 12:05:55) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ffmpeg
>>>
```

In your case you tried to run **ffmpeg** as a windows command in the **CMD** and you got the error

Answer (score 0):

Luc's answer is right. You can't just add any binary and use it to python.

But people have worked on making some apps available directly in python and FFmpeg is one of them. Here is the [github for the project](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python) and here is [the pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/ffmpeg-python/).

Now is it a good idea to use this instead of FFmpeg? It depends.
If you want to do simple video encoding and tasks, go ahead use the python bindings (that link FFmpeg to python commands). But keep in mind that they just call FFmpeg commands so FFmpeg will always be more powerful. Moreover, using python bindings makes you dependent on the developers behind the project. In that case the Github hasn't really been updated since 2019 so you might not get support if you encounter a bug and new features will probably not be released soon.